# Don't suggest current directory in autocomplete

Tags: bash, zsh, directory, autocomplete

I am a long time user of ZSH. It seems to me that I used to have this functionality a long time ago but then I rewrote my .zshrc (a long time ago) and now I miss this functionality every now and then. (Of course, being a long time ago, my memory may be faulty.)

What I want is that when I am autocompleting (such as pressing tab etc.) then I don't want suggestions from my current directory if I am starting from 1 level up (i.e., '..') or more.

So if I do

```
/usr/share$ cd ../<tab>
```

then I **don't** want my current directory as a suggestion

```
/usr/share$ cd ../share/
```

The question is for ZSH but I would love to know if it can be done in Bash too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://zshwiki.org/home/examples/compsys/ignore#ignore_parent_directory

```
zstyle ':completion:*:(cd|mv|cp):*' ignore-parents parent pwd
```

See also `info zsh ignore-parents` for details. Reproduced below for zsh 5.4.2:

> ### ignore-parents
>
> ```
>  The style is tested without a tag by the function completing
>  pathnames in order to determine whether to ignore the names of
>  directories already mentioned in the current word, or the name of
>  the current working directory.  The value must include one or both
>  of the following strings:
>
>  parent
>       The name of any directory whose path is already contained in
>       the word on the line is ignored.  For example, when completing
>       after foo/../, the directory foo will not be considered a
>       valid completion.
>
>  pwd
>       The name of the current working directory will not be
>       completed; hence, for example, completion after ../ will not
>       use the name of the current directory.
>
>  In addition, the value may include one or both of:
>
>  ..
>       Ignore the specified directories only when the word on the
>       line contains the substring '../'.
>
>  directory
>       Ignore the specified directories only when names of
>       directories are completed, not when completing names of files.
>
>  Excluded values act in a similar fashion to values of the
>  ignored-patterns style, so they can be restored to consideration by
>  the _ignored completer.
> ```

Comment: Thanks. It appears I already had this option set in my zshrc, but with '..' also which makes it almost never work.